# Pointers in Fortran

Tags: fortran

Im unsure how the below 2 in **C** can be represented in Fortran.

```
*VariableOne (Could be used possibly by using 'inout intent' in functions?

&VariableOne (No clue about how I could do this though)
```

Could someone tell me how I might be able to replicate this in Fortran? I looked up Pointers in Fortran but couldnt clearly understand what relates to the above two. I was hoping someone here would show me an equivalent to help me understand.

Comment: in fortran every function parameter is passed by reference, so technically that are poisters. But except from that I have no idea about fortran.

Comment: Your right about that. But im really puzzled about the '&'.

Comment: This is your third question with the same. You cannot translate from one language to another line by line. That is simply completely impossible, it doesn't work like that. You must learn both languages and understand the programming in both. Human spoken languages also cannot be translated word by word.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing two different concepts. Values in Fortran act as though they're passed by reference so you can modify a variable within a function and have its change reflected outside. The intent statements are there to specify what you're going to do with that dummy variable. intent(in) doesn't allow you to change that variable, intent(out) you use it to pass data out of a function and its value is undefined on entry, and intent(inout) means that it can both provide data to the function (not undefined on entry) and write to it as well.

But there are also explicit pointers you can use to dynamically allocate memory and act similarly to pointers in C.

Pointers in Fortran can't point to just anything. What they point to must have the target attribute or be a pointer. You also don't need to explicitly dereference a pointer to access its value. Here's a short example of what you can do with pointers and how they work:

```
real, pointer :: ptr(:) => null() !Can point to an array of reals or be allocated
real, target, allocatable :: trgt(:) !Array of reals
real, allocatable         :: array(:)
real, pointer             :: scalar => null() !Initially points to null to signify that it's not associated

!I can check if the pointer currently points to anything by using the associated function
!Be careful: the initial associaton status is undefined so you must set it to null or nullify it first
if (associated(ptr)) then 
    nullify(ptr) !Redundant in this example, same as setting it equal to null()       
 end if

allocate(ptr(3)) !I can allocate a pointer directly with memory for 3 elements 
allocate(trgt(5)) !Allocate the target with 5 elements
allocate(array(6)) !Allocate array

!Assign values to my freshly allocated variables
ptr = 1.0
trgt = 3.0
array = 5.0

deallocate(ptr) !Avoid memory leaks by deallocating memory before pointing to something else
ptr => trgt     !Pointer now points to the data stored in trgt. No need to use anything like '&' to reference trgt

ptr => array !Error because array does not have target attribute


scalar => ptr(1) !Both are pointers so no error, now points to a value of 3.0

print *, scalar + 5.0 !I can use this value directly without dereferencing it and prints 8.0
```

Comment: Could you show me what the equivalents of what I posted in my question would be? Like as if I were to do if I were translating code from C.

Comment: @Benjer There isn't an exact equivalent. You don't need to reference or de-reference pointers in Fortran like you do in C. If you want to assign a value to a pointer you just do `ptr = value` and if you want to point to something you just do `ptr => variable`

Comment: @Benjer if I do ptr = var does ptr contain the value of var or points to var? I am assuming the ptr will only contain the value of var and not point to the same address. If that is the case, why would ptr be used with the '=' operator? same functionality will be observed with a non pointer data type